# Beginners Coding Error, While Loop Triggering 2 Messages

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a beginner that just started learning python this Monday and one of the first hurdles I am getting into is while loops. I was trying to code a number guessing game and when I enter the correct answer it will give me "Wrong Guess" and "Correct Guess" as outputs. I have been staring at this problem wondering why this is happening but I can't figure it out. Can someone explain why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

```
secret_number = 9
guess = ''
i = 0
while guess != 9 and i < 3:
    guess = int(input("Guess Number: "))
    i += 1
    print('Wrong Guess!')
if guess == 9:
    print('Your Correct!')
if i == 3:
    print('You lost!')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have been staring at this problem wondering why this is happening but I can't figure it out." You first. Talk me through the code, step by step, and explain to me exactly what you think should happen instead, and why.

Comment: Hint: when the `while` loop is encountered for the first time, what is the value of `guess`? What is the value of `i`? Is `guess` equal to `9`? Is `i` less than `3`? Therefore, will the loop be entered? Now, what three things will happen, in order, *every time the loop executes*?

Comment: For future questions like this, please try an actual *discussion forum* like Reddit or Quora. It's hard to explain things properly in this format to beginners, because every beginner will have their own unique reasons for not understanding things - and we want to build a repository of *searchable* questions and answers. The format is not designed for talking back and forth to figure out the conceptual difficulty. You should also try to work on the skill of figuring out problems like this yourself. Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace your code line by line. Even if your answer was correct, the `print('Wrong Guess!')` would still execute.

Instead, I would check if the answer is correct inside the loop.

Note: there's a bug in your code - you should be using `secret_number` variable instead of explicitly writing 9.

You should also only add `i` for wrong guesses to prevent saying you lost although you did it in 3 tries.

```py
while guess != secret_number and i < 3:
    guess = int(input("Guess Number: "))
    if guess == secret_number :
        print('Your Correct!')
    else:    
        print('Wrong Guess!')
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were getting both the messages together when you entered 9 as the input because the `input` statement and the `Wrong Guess` statement are both in the same `while` loop. Meaning once the code asks you to guess a number, it would then increment `i` and then print `Wrong Guess`. Only after doing all three it would go back and check for the conditions of the `while` loop. Because the conditions fail, for guess = 9 the next lines of code are implemented. which give you the `Correct Guess` output.

To get the desired output do this,

```
secret_number = 9
guess = ''
i = 0

while True:
  if i < 3:
    guess = int(input("Guess Number: "))
    if guess == secret_number:
      print("Correct Guess")
      break
    else:
      print("Wrong Guess")

    i += 1

  else:
    print("You've run out of lives.")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to get what you're looking for:

```
secret_number = 9
guess = ''
i = 0
while guess!= secret_number and i<3:
    guess = int(input("Guess Number:"))
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("Your Correct!")
        break
    print("Wrong Guess!")
    i+=1

if i == 3:
    print('You Lost!')
```